# Adjust Chinese in webkit

Tags: css, flexbox, chinese-locale

I write a flexbox css style of appbar, but the layout is a bit weird in Chinese pattern on webkit.

[image]

The place highlight green background color is a flexbox div.

```
.green-background-color-div`
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: green;
`;
```

And the text is a textField's placeholder, the css of this textField.

```
.textField`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

  caret-color: gray;
  font-size: 18px;

  border: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: transparent;

  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  &::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    display: none;
  }
`;
```

There is no problem with common text.

[image]

How should I adjust my code to center Chinese like in Chrome?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use line height In CSS

```
.textField{
     line-height:26px; 
}
```

26px is an assumption. You can increase based on your design.

Comment: This code make the line height to the text, some language or some font-family may contain different line height. So this style is used to provide a line height to every language.